# directly execute windows store app

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store-app, rainmeter

I know the apps downloaded from the windows app store live under `C:\Users\username\Program Files\WindowsApps\...` but once you get here and find what would execute the app store application you'll get a `The application can only run in the context app container` error.

Example being trying to run `glcnd.exe` for the default reader app.

Is there a way to directly execute an app store app? Without having to create a batch script etc to do it.

I'm trying to link paths into a rainmeter configuration file to open app store apps as well as regular programs (file paths).