# How can I execute a Windows Store software with a command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, music

Related: [directly execute windows store app](https://superuser.com/questions/1044768/directly-execute-windows-store-app)  (has no answers.  )

---

Hello, I am asking with the idea to change my keyboard shortcut for Media:  [How can I run another app when pressing the calculator key on my keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/192763/how-can-i-run-another-app-when-pressing-the-calculator-key-on-my-keyboard)
(being the key number in this case under `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\16"` )
I want it to open the Spotify App that I have downloaded using Windows 10 App Store.
The thing is that I have no clue where the ".exe" file is located.
Is there a special command to open spotify? Like the one that the Steam game platform has for it's own games.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I tried something, so the answer was actually really simple.
Turns out the store creates a PATH variable so I tried WIN+R and 'spotify' opens the spotify app from the store.
So the solution is to create the String in the registry key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\16`
And the value it's just "spotify", no need for a complete path to an ".exe"
And done.
Hope it helps